# Getting the first word from each line?

Tags: java, regex, string

Having a hard time getting the first word from each line. Any ideas why it's outputting blank files?

The program takes the following text as input:

```
abecedism   word created from the initials of words in a phrase
ablaut  variation in root vowel of words to change meaning
acronym word formed from initial letters of another word
acrophonic  using a symbol for the initial sound of a thing
acroteleutic    phrase or words at the end of a psalm
adversative word or phrase expressing opposition
```

And the aim is to get the results to look like this:

```
abecedism   
ablaut  
acronym 
acrophonic  
acroteleutic    
adversative
```

Here is the code so far:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String fileNameOutput = "OutputFile.txt";
    String fileName = "InputWords.txt";
    Charset cs = Charset.defaultCharset();
    try (BufferedReader bReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName), cs)) {
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileNameOutput);
        int lineNum = 0;
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lineNum++;
            if (line.split(" ").length > 1) continue;
            outputStream.println(line);
        }
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if there are more than one blank space between say these two words from the first line `abecedism   word`? Your `line.split(" ")` won't work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (line.split(" ").length > 1) continue;
```

checks if line contains more than one words/tokens and if it does it immediately starts new iteration which means you are skipping rest of code after `continue` which prevents you from executing

```
outputStream.println(line);
```

and since each line in your file has more that one word you are not adding anything to result file.

---

Your code could probably be simplified a little with Scanner class which allows us to iterate over words/tokens using `next()` method.

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
     PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileNameOutput);) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        outputStream.println(sc.next());// write first word from line
        sc.nextLine();// consume rest of text from that line
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note: don't call `close()` inside try section. If some exception would occur `outputStream.close();` for your `PrintWriter outputStream` wouldn't be called which could make a lot of problems. You should move declaration of closable resources as part of try-with-resources.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks mate. Spent hours on this damn problem

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies here:

```
if (line.split(" ").length > 1) continue;
```

Each line has more than 1 space, so the code:

```
outputStream.println(line.split(" ")[0]);
```

is never executed, since `continue` skips directly to the next while iteration So remove the `if (line.split(" ").length > 1) continue;` check

**EDIT**
Added line.split(" ")[0] in print message to only get first word

Comment: Ah thank you lol. But it leaves one problem still. This solution gives results where the first 2 words are printed out each line. Any ideas how it can be changed to only get the first word?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `String#split(String)` to split it where it encounter space. The result is an array. Choose the first index of the latter.

```
outputStream.println(line);
```

should be replaced with

```
outputStream.println(line.split(" ")[0]);
```

---

PS : For this to work `if (line.split(" ").length > 1) continue;` must be changed to allow Strings with more than one word.

Comment: nah this statement won't execute if the condition is false, which it is. (still gives blank file)

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Just saw it. What is the meaning of this condition? Why is it there?

Comment: It's supposed to check if there is a blank space after the first word xD

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Well, it is a word if there is a blank space after. No?

Comment: yeah exactly, and i only want to extract the first words which always leave by 1 space behind it. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte I'm sorry but it does not for me. But Roel understood it. Did my answer help you though? Otherwise I can always delete it.

Comment: In part, yeah. thanks. Still need to figure out why it's spitting out two words and not just one though

Answer (score 1):

That `split` is unnecessary, you can do basically

```
while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
    lineNum++;
    int spaceIndex = line.indexOf(" ");
    String firstWord = spaceIndex > -1 ? line.substring(0, spaceIndex) : line;
    outputStream.println(firstWord );
}
```

You can add another check if the line is empty...

Comment: produces a blank file

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte yeah, you need to `print` the `firstWord`. I've added that in my answer, though it was kinda obvious...

Answer (score 1):

That's it

```
  public static void main(String args[]){

     String fileNameOutput = "OutputFile.txt";
        String fileName = "InputWords.txt";

        Charset cs = Charset.defaultCharset() ;
        try (BufferedReader bReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName), cs)){

            PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileNameOutput); 
            int lineNum = 0;
            String line = null;

            while ( (line = bReader.readLine() ) != null ) {
               lineNum++;

                outputStream.println(line.split(" ")[0]);

            }
                outputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

Comment: These results also seem to output the first two words of each sentence and not one..

Answer (score 1):

you need to use find the value of index of  the first blank space 
then use substring methode to cut the string line from 0 to index of f

Answer (score 1):

if you have input as string you can simply use a regular expression to get it

```
String[] words = input.split("[ ].*$*[\n\r]{0,}");
```

and if you are reading from file then either you can read entire string from file using

```
String input = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("..your path..")));
```

or you can iterate over each line if you have large data and you don't want to do it at a glance, then you can follow other approaches as well, and extract first word from each line.